# how can i parse a url json code to delete items an a listview

Tags: android

i need some help  please... In my popup menu i have a delete option to delete items in a listview

how can i parse this url json to delete the items in the listview

this is the result of my  list view

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        codigo.setText(recode);
        nombre.setText(reNombre);
        nroComprobante.setText(reNumero);

        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Compra.this, prod,
                R.layout.item_carrito, new String[]{"renglon", "codigo", "descrip", "precio"},
                new int[]{R.id.tvreglon, R.id.tvcode, R.id.tvdescrip, R.id.tvprec});
        lista_eligida.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("ADAP", String.valueOf(adapter));
        registerForContextMenu(lista_eligida);

    }

}
```

and this is my popup menu code...

```
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int id = info.position;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.del:
            String url = "http://www.air-intra.com/apps/air-app/agregar.php?token=" + Token_Recibido + "&codiart=" + codigo + "&oper=Q&renglon=" + reglo + "";
```

// what can i do??... should i parse the new json again.?..
//i just want to delete a item when i clicked on delete option on my popup menu thank you

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand that what do you want to do with the url and how it is connected to the list. Please elaborate a little bit more. So I can understand and can help you.

Comment: the url is a json result  when i tried to parse it, i have a exception error HTTPHANDLER is null

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Comment: Did you find the solution? Is is working?

Comment: no.. is not !! i have the same error ..HttpHandle = null 
look like he dosent make the connection...

Answer (score 0):

this is how a did it

```
      String url = "http://www.air-intra.com/apps/air-app/agregar.php?token=" + Token_Recibido + "&codiart=" + codigo + "&oper=Q&renglon=" + reglo + "";
            HttpHandler she = new HttpHandler();
            JSONObject jsonStr = she.makeServiceCall(url);


            try {
                JSONObject    jsonObj = new JSONObject((Map) jsonStr);
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PRR");
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String codig = c.getString("codigo");
                    String des = c.getString("descrip");
                    String prec = c.getString("precio");
                    String reglon = c.getString("renglon");

                    Log.d("REGLON", String.valueOf(reglon));

                    HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                    contacto.put("codigo", codig);
                    contacto.put("descrip", des);
                    contacto.put("precio", prec);
                    contacto.put("renglon", reglon);
                    reg = "" + reglon;
                    prod.add(contacto);
```

Comment: As per your code above you are holding references to your views and performing a setText which would cause a Memory leak in case of orientation change. Just use a call back mechanism or Handler to avoid that.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your API call code given above with this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {

             String url = "http://www.air-intra.com/apps/air-app/agregar.php?token=" + Token_Recibido + "&codiart=" + codigo + "&oper=Q&renglon=" + reglo + "";
        HttpHandler she = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = she.makeServiceCall(url);


        try {
            JSONObject    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PRR");

           prop.clear(); \\Add this line in your code here.

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                String codig = c.getString("codigo");
                String des = c.getString("descrip");
                String prec = c.getString("precio");
                String reglon = c.getString("renglon");

                Log.d("REGLON", String.valueOf(reglon));

                HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                contacto.put("codigo", codig);
                contacto.put("descrip", des);
                contacto.put("precio", prec);
                contacto.put("renglon", reglon);
                reg = "" + reglon;
                prod.add(contacto);

            if(jsonStr != null) {
                System.out.println("success");
            } else {
                System.out.println("failed");
            }

            return jsonStr;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            System.out.println("result=="+result);
        }
    }.execute();
```

The issue I guess is that you are trying to make the API call on Main Thread that is not allowed. So I have put it in background. I have just put your given code in my code. Your code doesn't seem complete. SO complete your code before executing.

Comment: thank you @Zohaib for your help but he dosent work .. i remind you ..the code is inside a popup menu (Case R.id.delete)...you think i can call a new asyncTask..?

Comment: Yeah you can call the AsyncTask from anywhere, AsyncTask is actually used to perform the task in background without bothering the main thread.

Comment: Thank you  a lot Zohaib its work , now i got another problem ...when i delete the item  he use the same listview to give me back the result.... like if i had...
 1)
2)
3) and i delete the second item ... i have now 
1)
2)
3)
1)
3)

Comment: whenever you are getting data, intilaize the array before adding data into it.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I hava added a new line. Add that line at the same place in your code where I added it.

Comment: Work perfectly Zohaib ..Thx for your great help ..apreciate that